# How can I test for an implicit HTTP status code (200) in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, httpresponse, http-status-codes

I'm unit-testing some caching code in an ASP.NET MVC2 controller. My code explicitly sets a `304 Not Modified` if the cache headers are OK - which is great, because I can mock the HttpResponse in the controller context and verify that the StatusCode has been set accordingly.

If I **don't** explicitly set a response code, the controller returns a `200 OK` (which I can see in the HTTP response headers in Chrome), but I can't see any way to verify this in a unit test - any expectations for setting the response status or status code just don't get satisfied. It appears to be some sort of default behaviour created by the ASP.NET MVC controller pipeline - and even after invoking `result.ExecuteResult(controller.ControllerContext)` I can't see the response code being set to 200 anywhere. Anyone written a test for this scenario?